# How to enable "Hey Cortana" on Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cortana

I can set Cortana on my Laptop running Windows 10 Pro to respond when I say "Hey Cortana" and I don't even need to touch the Laptop to command something to Cortana. I can enable or disable this in settings. But for my Lumia 535 running Windows 10 build 14393.693, I neither can enable this nor I could find a setting for this.

[image]

[image]

Sometimes I put my phone under my bed and its very difficult to look for it to do something. So is there anyway that I can make Cortana to do something like texting or setting reminder without bothering to go to my phone, enter my PIN and then manually type the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Hey Cortana" feature is only available on a limited number of mobile devices. Specifically, the list includes the Lumia 950, 950 XL, 930, 1520 and Icon. The reason is that it requires specialised hardware that's only available in high-end (Snapdragon 800 series) chipsets.

So you're not seeing the option to enable "Hey Cortana" because your Lumia 535 simply does not support the feature.

Sources:

- [Hey Cortana availability by mobile device and region](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/instantanswers/aac6989a-f78f-3d79-0d20-1cb6523ef798/hey-cortana-availability-by-mobile-device-and-region)
- [What exactly is SensorCore? Answers inside...](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8-1/309085-what-exactly-sensorcore-answers-inside.html)

Comment: So the absence of that setting in any device will eventually mean that this feature is not available for that device because its hardware is incapable of handling this feature?

Comment: @User5 Correct.

Answer (score 1):

***Update***:  *It appears that this specific model, Lumia 535, does not support "Hey Cortana".  It appears that "Hey Cortana" is only available on phones that have the Snapdragon 8xx series chipsets.*

For other devices, like the Lumia 950 and 950 XL, you can perform the following steps:

1. Press the **Search button** on your phone, or launch the **Cortana
   app** from the Start Menu.
2. When Cortana opens, press the hamburger menu in the upper-left, then
   choose **Settings**.
3. The first option is "**Hey Cortana**".  You can turn it on from
   there.

Comment: I can't found it in settings. See the screenshot

Comment: When I wrote my answer, you had not put up the screenshots.  It appears that your device does not support the "Hey Cortana" feature.  I will edit my answer.