# Make Cortana listen on Cortana-app startup

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cortana, lumia-640

When I click on the Cortana tile, Cortana doesn't listen (to "hey Cortana") until I click the small microphone button. Is there a way to have it listen right after I click on its tile?

Comment: Related: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/14751/how-to-enable-hey-cortana-on-windows-10-mobile?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. But holding the "Search" button on your phone should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. If that's true, it's unfortunate. I would like to have an ***easy*** way to make it listen. Thanks again.

Comment: That would indeed be nice (and is currently quite possible, if Microsoft would just program it). It should be noted that one advantage of the current way (holding the search button) is that you can do it from above the lockscreen instead of having to unlock your phone.